# Rails 3 Two Fields Uniqueness Validation when combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `Friendship`  where `:friend_id` is also a foreign key as `:user_id`

```
friendships
id | user_id | friend_id
```

I'm aware that validating the uniqueness of the two fields would be something like this

```
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :friend_id}
```

But is there a way to validate

```
user_id = 1, friend_id = 3
user_id = 3, friend_id = 1
```

so that only 
`user_id = 1, friend_id = 3` is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validate :relationship_uniqueness

def relationship_uniqueness

  existing_record = Friendship.find(:first, :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?", user_id, friend_id])
  unless existing_record.blank?
    errors.add(:user_id, "has already been saved for this relationship")
  end

end
```

Comment: It needs to be like :conditions => ["user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?", friend_id, user_id]). And it works !! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reading the question more closely I now think that it's really

```
validates :friend_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is hard problem.

> How do you model a symmetric relationship?

Last time I did this I decided that in fact it is not symmetric.
For an idea of how to model this look at [Disapora's `Contact` class](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/app/models/contact.rb)

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :person
  validates :person, :presence => true
  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :person_id, :scope => :user_id
end
```

You'll note they don't do anything special to ensure uniqueness.

What they do instead is carefully consider each point of the interaction that creates or breaks a friendship. We need to be careful to wrap them in transactions.

Basically, when a user sends a "friend request"

1. We create a Contact from the "user" to the "friend" with a status of "pending"
2. We create a Contact from the "friend" to the "user" with a status of "requested"

When the "friend" accepts this "request"

1. Both Contacts are set to "accepted"

If the "friend" chooses to break the friendship

1. Both Contacts are deleted

Each of these actions need to be done in a transaction.

As long as these transactions are one correctly we should never have a one-way friendship.

Comment: Yea, I have seen many examples of creating a contact model like this. I knew my way would be a pain. It's just that I'm considering a situation when you don't need a status field, and I just wanna keep the table small. I probably should just go back to the old way then.

Comment: With one record, if we want to know "is user 1 connected to user 2?" with just one record, we need to say "WHERE (user_id=1 AND friend_id=2) OR (user_id=2 AND friend_id=1)". Not very efficient

Comment: the alternative is to enforce "user_id < friend_id"

Comment: Well, all these methods will only work when we validate on rails side, once we getting into database and insert the record manually, everything would fall apart. Best solution is to come up with a way to enforce this on the database side.

Comment: everything *can* be done in the database via a trigger, but usually its not worth doing. If your code does something like this carefully within a transaction, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One More!

```
def unique_relationship?
    self.class.where("(user_id = ? and friend_id = ?) or 
                      (user_id = ? and friend_id = ?)", 
                      user_id, friend_id, friend_id, user_id).empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I thought of a way to work around this, but it's very messy

```
friendships
id
1

friend_lists
id | friendship_id | user_id
1  |       1       |   1
2  |       1       |   3
```

This way, I will have to make sure one `friendship_id` can only be entered twice into `friend_lists`, and do

```
validates :friendship_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}
```

Comment: then you need to ensure that each friendship has exactly 2 users

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
validate :unique_relationship

def unique_relationship
  (user_id.to_s + friend_id.to_s).uniq
end
```

Comment: this is interesting, let me give a try

Comment: I don't get it. this code creates a string then tries to call `uniq` on it.

Comment: yea, I got NoMethodError: undefined method 'uniq' for "31":String. But I like the approach

Comment: Yes, I've also just posted a question about how to do it this way - but correctly.

Comment: Yea, I didn't put title as in the correct way. So ppl might think I'm just asking old question.