# Rails: how to make a friendship system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

```
#friendships model
id | user_id | friend_id
```

The problem is that

1. `friendship` can only retreived by `inverse_friends` and `friends`. I want to retrive all `friends` at one, no matter who create the relationship.
2. How can I make the `friendship` unique? So

For 1, I think I can hack it by doing something like 
`current_user.friends + current_user.inverse_friends`. But not sure if this the right way.

For 2, I find [Rails 3 Two Fields Uniqueness Validation when combined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106750/rails-3-two-fields-uniqueness-validation-when-combined), and still looking for more straight forward solution.